# Problems with configuring WRT54GL

Tags: wrt54gl

I have a Linksys's WRT54GL router and when I try to config it I always get the same error: "value is illegal!".

The funny thing is that at beginning I have managed to input all the data and it worked correctly... Later I created factory reset and tried to do the configuration again and now it doesn't work... It doesn't accept inputted data...

Any idea? I haved added print screen as well... Thanks for your help!

[image: Print screen]

Comment: You should consider installing Tomato on your router instead, anyway - http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato

Comment: I have installed Tomato on my old router and it worked great! But this one is new... So it must work with pre-installed software... 

Comment: I didn't think they still made the WRT54GL, or any other wireless routers without wireless-N.

Answer (score 2):

There may be some corruption in your NVRAM. You'll need to clear it out, which will require cleaning out all of your settings and configuration in the router. You mentioned you tried a factory reset -- the reset in the web interface, or just hitting the reset button for 5 or 10 seconds may not work -- it's best to try for a full 30 seconds. Please make sure that any of these resets are appropriate for your router before proceeding, because there may be a small chance that you could "brick" or otherwise break your router.

The first thing to try is a "30 second" reset:

```
1. With the unit powered on, press and hold the reset
     button on back of unit for 30 seconds.
```

The 30 second reset should fix most issues.

Another thing you might want to try is the 30/30/30 reset, rather than just a normal reset. It works for some routers, but not all. Please make sure that this reset is appropriate for your router before doing it, because there may be a small chance that you could make your router unusable.

```
1. With the unit powered on, press and hold the reset
     button on back of unit for 30 seconds.
2. Without releasing the reset button, unplug the unit
     and hold reset for another 30 seconds.
3. Plug the unit back in STILL holding the reset button
     a final 30 seconds.
```

Comment: I've tried the following: 30 seconds reset, firmware upgrading... None of it worked correctly... Will try 30/30/30 but before that I will take it back to store and request new one... will report! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an error in your netmask.

Netmask: 255.255.192.0, or in binary: 11111111.11111111.11000000.00000000
Gateway: 84.255.192.0

That seems to point at a network range of 84.255.192.0 - 84.255.255.255.  Or equivalent of 64 /24 (aka class C) network ranges, which is something a small to medium company would use.

I suspect that it should be 255.255.255.192 (aka 64 IP adresses, which is quite luxerious for a home network and even not bad for a small firm or two).